# Lucene : why the highlighting does an extra word splitting ?

Tags: java, lucene

I'm using Lucene for a small project, here's how I highlighting:

```
Fields tvFields = indexReader.getTermVectors(docId);
TokenStream contentTokenStream = TokenSources.getTokenStream(CONTENT_FILED_NAME, tvFields, content, analyzer, -1);
highlighter.getBestFragments(contentTokenStream, content, 3);
```

I thought tvFields already contains the term vector of `filename`, but in fact, when `highlighter` executing, the program take another word splitting. Since the content might be pretty huge, this step takes too much time.

Is there way that I can avoid this `extra` word splitting ? I've tried to index the `content` field with `setStoreTermVectors(true)` in FieldType, but it doesn't work !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, by using a different highlighter.

- [FastVectorHighlighter](https://lucene.apache.org/core/6_2_0/highlighter/org/apache/lucene/search/vectorhighlight/FastVectorHighlighter.html#getFieldQuery-org.apache.lucene.search.Query-)  : Performs well on large fields, and since you are already storing TermVectors, this is probably a good choice.  Just make sure you also store Term Vector Offsets and Positions (`setStoreTermVectorOffsets` and `setStoreTermVectorPositions`).

  ```
  FastVectorHighlighter highlighter = new FastVectorHighlighter(true, true);
  String highlightedResult = highlighter.getBestFragment(
          highlighter.getFieldQuery(myQuery),
          indexReader,
          docId,
          CONTENT_FIELD_NAME,
          50 //char length of fragment
      );
  ```
- [PostingsHighlighter](https://lucene.apache.org/core/6_2_0/highlighter/org/apache/lucene/search/postingshighlight/PostingsHighlighter.html) : Must be indexed with `IndexOptions.DOCS_AND_FREQS_AND_POSITIONS_AND_OFFSETS`.

  ```
  PostingsHighlighter highlighter2 = new PostingsHighlighter();
  TopDocs docs = indexSearcher.search(myQuery, 10);
  String[] highlightedResults = highlighter.highlight(
          CONTENT_FIELD_NAME, 
          myQuery, 
          indexSearcher, 
          docs
      );
  ```